# How to interpret linear mixed model with/without random intercept fitted in nlme

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interpretation, intercept

I fitted two models using the `Oats` data from `nlme`:

```
library(nlme)
fm4OatsB <- lme( yield ~ nitro, data = Oats,
                 random =list(Block = pdCompSymm(~ Variety - 1)))

fm4OatsB2 <- lme( yield ~ nitro, data = Oats,
                  random =list(Block = pdCompSymm(~ Variety)))
```

Result of `summary(fm4OatsB)`:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Oats 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  603.0418 614.2842 -296.5209

Random effects:
 Formula: ~Variety - 1 | Block
 Structure: Compound Symmetry
                   StdDev   Corr       
VarietyGolden Rain 18.20788            
VarietyMarvellous  18.20788 0.635      
VarietyVictory     18.20788 0.635 0.635
Residual           12.86695            

Fixed effects:  yield ~ nitro 
               Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 81.87222  6.945283 65 11.78818       0
nitro       73.66667  6.781480 65 10.86292       0
 Correlation: 
      (Intr)
nitro -0.293

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.74380733 -0.66475232  0.01710384  0.54298795  1.80298808 

Number of Observations: 72
Number of Groups: 6
```

Results of `summary(fm4OatsB2)`:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Oats 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  601.1382 612.3807 -295.5691

Random effects:
 Formula: ~Variety | Block
 Structure: Compound Symmetry
                  StdDev   Corr         
(Intercept)       14.14419              
VarietyMarvellous 14.14419 -0.158       
VarietyVictory    14.14419 -0.158 -0.158
Residual          12.79030              

Fixed effects:  yield ~ nitro 
               Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 82.00534  6.182291 65 13.26456       0
nitro       73.66667  6.741078 65 10.92802       0
 Correlation: 
      (Intr)
nitro -0.327

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-1.59290296 -0.71228013 -0.04067677  0.59904662  1.76541336 

Number of Observations: 72
Number of Groups: 6
```

Result of `getVarCov(fm4OatsB)`:

```
Random effects variance covariance matrix
                   VarietyGolden Rain VarietyMarvellous VarietyVictory
VarietyGolden Rain             331.53            210.42         210.42
VarietyMarvellous              210.42            331.53         210.42
VarietyVictory                 210.42            210.42         331.53
  Standard Deviations: 18.208 18.208 18.208
```

Result of `getVarCov(fm4OatsB2)`:

```
Random effects variance covariance matrix
                  (Intercept) VarietyMarvellous VarietyVictory
(Intercept)           200.060           -31.659        -31.659
VarietyMarvellous     -31.659           200.060        -31.659
VarietyVictory        -31.659           -31.659        200.060
  Standard Deviations: 14.144 14.144 14.144
```

Page 161 of "Mixed-effects models in S and S-PLUS" well explained why `fm4OatsB` is equivalent to `fm4Oats <- lme( yield ~ nitro, data = Oats, random = ~ 1 | Block/Variety )`. But I get lost how to interpret the  different variance-covariance matrices of `fm4OatsB` and `fm4OatsB2` resulting from `getVarCov`. Is it possible to calculate numbers in `getVarCov(fm4OatsB2)` from `getVarCov(fm4OatsB)` or vice versa? The `-1` in `fm4OatsB` seems to remove random intercept component, but I do not fully understand what it means.